# copy A table to B table with extra unique column

Tags: php, mysql

in my database i have 2 table , orders and cart , i would like to copy the cart table to the order table i can do that using this statement

```js
INSERT INTO Orders
SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
FROM   cart
```

the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() will replace the extra unique column but i don't want to use timestamp as unique , i would like to have something else , because am scared 2 user will order in the same time , then they will have the same order id

Comment: Add a Cart_ID column that's set to AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: INSERT INTO Orders (fields)
SELECT  fields,'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'
FROM cart

Comment: this will give different cart id to each row , but i want them all with the same id like in timestamp , so when user order again he will have different order id for that order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use current date and time epoch format for uniqueness of record.

For Example :-

Assuming that 1501216777000 is in milliseconds:
GMT: Friday, July 28, 2017 4:39:37.216 AM
Your time zone: Friday, July 28, 2017 10:09:37.216 AM GMT+05:30

So 1501216777000 this string can be your unique. 2 users can not place order in same time now because this epoch format is in milliseconds.

Comment: INSERT INTO Orders
SELECT *,(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())*1000)
FROM   cart

Comment: thank you this is work , but there are problem , this will work only one time , the second time it will not work and i have no idea why

Comment: ok i fix it , i put column name instead of *  and its work like magic  thanks a lot

Comment: It's not true that users cannot place orders at the same time, only that it is unlikely.

Comment: yest true , hope no one will order at the same , time until i find more unique function :D

Answer (score 0):

Add a Primary Key ID to your cart table, with AUTO INCREMENT. So you will have an unique value increasing automatically.

```
ALTER TABLE cart ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: this will give different orderid for each product , all the row must have the same order id , the code i post is working , and it do what i want , but i want to replace the function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() with different function that will give me unique value

Answer (score 0):

You could simply concatenate something unique with the timestamp. e.g. `current_timestamp() + '-' + User_ID` to provide a number that will be unique per-user.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO Orders (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL_TIME)
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
FROM   cart
```

Always put column name instead of * when you try t insert value in table.

Comment: the code i post is working , and it do what i want , but i want to replace the function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() with different function that will give me unique value . and thanks for the suggest i will do it